# Remove elements from a multiple file input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am able to select multiple files using the multiple property on file input tag.
however i am wondering how to delete a single element.

I know that you can't manipulate the file input on its own because its a security hole and that browsers do not allow that, but i would like to point you to the jquery upload plugin : https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload.

This plugin allows you to remove individual elements, there is no flash there. all is javascript and the html5 api!

oh and i am aware of uploadify, i just want to stay with pure js and html file api.

Comment: Have you tried getting into the code in the jQuery-File-Upload plugin to see how its doing it?

Comment: I solve it temporally by adding a hidden select where i add the discarded files. Then i upload all files to server and if the select param contains some file of the uploaded then don't save it. I know its not correct but cannot find the right solution.

Answer (score 5):

**EDIT:**

After better understanding what you were looking for, I whipped up another [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/_andrewclarkson/sBYHN/) where (from your JS) you're able to access the elements individually.

What I did was use the [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/) and [File Readers](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-upload/#dfn-filereader):

- Add an event handler to the input: `$("#fileInput").on("change", processFiles);​`
- In your event handler use: `event.target.files` to access the [FileList Object](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-upload/#filelist-section)
- Use a FileReader: `var reader = new FileReader();` to read the file
- You can read the files in a number of ways (binary, text, url, etc), I chose data url: `reader.readAsDataURL(file);`
- Add a callback from the FileReader `reader.onload = function(){...};`
- *Within the callback* push the result: `event.target.result` to an array

From there you can do what ever you want with it!

I just sent the data to an echo server, then generated links with the responses, [Check It](http://jsfiddle.net/_andrewclarkson/sBYHN/).

Comment: Your code doesn't handle every file individually. This is no a solution!

Comment: So you need to be able to upload a list of selected files _one by one_ like the example you gave?

Comment: Basically what i want to do is select multiple files at once and then being able to upload one by one. So it would be something like a queue system, therefore the server receive only one single file at time and not an array of files.

Comment: Tight! that's what the demo does. Basically, you read the files from the input, store them in memory, and then upload them one by one, when you want (on the click of a button?) via an AJAX POST. I had never really tried this before :)

Comment: But you are reading files into the memory, i am dealing with big files, usually 2gb files. wouldn't your code kill the browser in case of selecting a file which is 2-3 gb ?

Comment: Perfect!!!... Works like VOODOO.... Thanks a million.. WORKS in all Human Friendly browesers... EXCEPT of course King_Internet_Explorer;  i get the following error:: *SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'length': object is null or undefined*___ but Who cares?

Comment: May be if Ok... is it possible to Remove individual files from Queue?.. As in having two  buttons, Upload and Remove... thanx again

Comment: This is great. I've never used the File API and was looking for something functional to get me started. This is perfect. Thanks!